# Как могут повлиять 50 "грязных" экземпляров из 1000 обучающего набора на точность предсказывания нейронной сети?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Скажите, пожалуйста, **на сколько** сильно могут повлиять 50 "грязных" экземпляров из 1000 обучающего набора на **точность** предсказывания нейронной сети? Допустим, что я обучаю нейронную сеть распозновать машины, 950 из 1000 экземпляров моего обучающего набора данных содержат машины в хорошем качестве, остальные 50 экземпляров содержат фото чего угодно, но только не машин? Интересно узнать.

Comment: что у вас за архитектура НС? Что именно вы предсказываете - наличие любой машины на картинке или марку машины? Какие у вас целевые метки (`labels`)? Правильные ли метки у 50 "грязных" экземпляров?

Comment: Извините, что не указал сразу это. Архитектура.. Это модель YoloV3, object detection алгоритм. Пытаюсь найти машину на фотографии, неважно какой марки. А целевые метки у "грязных" экземпляров могут указывать, допустим, на светофор или на велосипед.

Comment: Так какая у вас классификация (архитектура выходного слоя) - бинарная, multiclass или multilabel?

Comment: @MaxU, не пойму какая у меня из этих трёх. Всего 1 класс - автомобиль.

Comment: как же мы вам можем помочь если вы сами не знаете что делаете?? В вашем описании в вопросе  слишком много пробелов для того, чтобы можно было что-то посоветовать или ответить...

Comment: @MaxU, ладно, всё равно спасибо за попытку помочь!

Comment: Мне кажется, что имеется в виду бинарная, потому что предполагается две вероятности - вероятность того, что на картинке машина, и обратная. Отвечая на вопрос: нет; лучше всего даже сделать картинок без машин больше именно потому, что сети надо откуда-то брать опыт о том, как вообще НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ выглядеть машины.